# mydomainname.com not working with https

Tags: ssl-certificate, https

I have create a self signed SSL Certificate for testing purpose and I have configure the generated certificate with my virtual hosts file. But when I tried to access my domainname.com with https://mydomainname.com its not working. Mozilla gives the error page "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at mydomainname.com.". I have window vista machine. And my virtual hosts file is as follows.

my virtual hosts file :

```
<IfDefine SSL>
 <VirtualHost mydomainname.com:80>
       #ServerName www.mydmainnamw.com:8080
       #DocumentRoot "C:/.../My Company/My Sites/johnbokma.com/site/web"
       #CustomLog logs/lc.johnbokma.com.access.log combined
       #ErrorLog logs/lc.johnbokma.com.error.log

       SSLEngine on
       SSLCertificateFile C:/Program Files (x86)/ApacheSoftwareFoundation/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt 
       SSLCertificateKeyFile C:/Program Files (x86)/ApacheSoftwareFoundation/conf/ssl.key/server.key

       SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
       CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
       "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

 </VirtualHost>
<IfDefine SSL>
```

Comment: do not cross post, please; if a Question is not appropriate for the site you post it on we will move it to the correct site.

Answer (score 1):

or change VirtualHost mydomainname.com:80 to VirtualHost mydomainname.com:443

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're trying to run HHTPS over port 80 (per the virtual hosts definition) which isn't going to work very well when the rest of the world uses port 443.

Comment: Yeah, you'll want another VirtualHost on something besides port 80. When you type "https" the browser is defaulting to port 443, and doesn't find anything. It may actually work if you typed https:// blahblah.com:80 , but that's pretty silly.

Answer (score 0):

Having tried to clarify the stuff you've posted above, it appears that you're running the app on port 80.  Try https://mydomainname.com:80/ and see what happens.

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. I have tried with 80 port but it not working.